# Uncaught TypeError: signinUsingGoogle is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add firebase authentication to my website. but having an error. I'm trying to solve this last three days. below I'm shared my code and error. i use react router dom, firebase authentication system with react js. when I click sign in with google button, it show hello in console, that's right. but after it, I'm facing this error.

the error is,
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMiWo.png)

in useFirebase.js file, I write below code,

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import initializeConfig from '../Firebase/Firebase.init';

initializeConfig();

const useFirebase = () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    

    const signinUsingGoogle = () => {
        return signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    }



    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribed = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            if (user) {
                setUser(user)
            }
            else {
                setUser({})
            }
        });
        return () => unsubscribed;
    }, [])



    const signOut = () => {
        signOut(auth)
            .then(() => {
            
        })
    }
    return (
        user,
        signinUsingGoogle,
        signOut

    );
};

export default useFirebase;
```

and in signin.js file, I write the below code,

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useAuth from "../../Hooks/useAuth";
import "./Signin.css";

const Signin = () => {
    const { signinUsingGoogle } = useAuth();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigateUrl = location?.state?.from || "/home";
    const GoogleSignin = () => {
        console.log("hello");
        signinUsingGoogle()
            .then((result) => {
                navigate(navigateUrl);
            })
            .finally(() => {});
    };

    return (
        <div className="signin d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mx-auto">
            <div className="signin-card p-3 m-3">
                <img
                    src="https://c.tenor.com/9Xf0d7BGQ5oAAAAC/computer-log-in.gif"
                    alt="img not found"
                    width="360px"
                />
                <div className="d-grid gap-2 mt-3 text-center">
                    <Button variant="primary" size="lg" onClick={GoogleSignin}>
                        <h5>
                            <i className="fab fa-google-plus"></i> Google
                        </h5>
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="secondary" size="lg" className="github">
                        <h5>
                            <i className="fab fa-github"></i> Github
                        </h5>
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="secondary" size="lg" className="facebook">
                        <h5>
                            <i className="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i> Facebook
                        </h5>
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Signin;
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're returning from the useAuth hook is not correct. If you want to destructure the returned object, you should return it this way:

```
return {
        user,
        signinUsingGoogle,
        signOut

    };
```